Razorpay Linked account has any UI for collecting user details
I am using razorpay route , is there any hosted Ui page for collecting user kyc details and bank details and how i verify account detail if no?
I am trying to implement razorpay linked account , anyone has the answer for this.

You can add the accounts for route under the "Accounts" tab in the "Route" page of Razorpay Dashboard. You can also batch upload accounts if you have to add many accounts. Attaching an image for reference

